# Solve for $p$ from $1 - (1-p)^{52} = {4/98}$

Tags: polynomials

I have this equation:

$$1 - (1-p)^{52} = {4\over 98}$$

I tried some math websites but can't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-(1-p)^{52}=\frac{4}{98}\iff$

$(1-p)^{52}=1-\frac{4}{98}\iff$

$(1-p)^{52}=\frac{94}{98}\iff$

$1-p=\sqrt[52]{\frac{94}{98}}\iff$

$p=1-\sqrt[52]{\frac{94}{98}}\approx0.0008$

Comment: Now I am very confused, because the same formula came up to 0.0008 in another related question. check this out... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649435/probability-of-an-event-based-on-percentage-in-fixed-lapse-of-time

Comment: @PepitoFernandez: So???? What exactly is there to be confused about? Same equation, same result!!!

Comment: what about the other solution?

Comment: Line 4 should say $\pm\sqrt[52]{\frac{94}{98}}$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Did you just down-vote me for this reason??? If anything, a root of degree $52$ has $52$ solutions (some possibly complex), not only $2$ as you have suggested!!! The question in its current context is obviously not about all possible $52$ solutions, so this remark of yours does not contribute anything here!!!

Comment: No, I wasn't the one to down-vote your answer. I just supposed that the point of the question was to solve the equation in real numbers, in which case there are two solutions. If the point was to solve in complex numbers, there would be indeed 52 solutions. However, nothing in this question tells us that the second solution (which would result from taking negative root) is discarded.

Comment: @Wojowu: Nothing in the question tells us that all the complex solutions should be discarded, yet, you've still discarded them in your comment. Your assumption that the solution shound be given in real numbers is just as good as my assumption that a single (non-negative) solution is the goal here.

Comment: @Wojowu: In fact, my assumption is even more solid, as the question is obviously about probability - both from the given equation (which is a "pretty standard" solution for a very specific type of probability question), as well as from OP's later comment to my answer. And since probability is a non-negative value, I don't see any reason to specify the negative one.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "obviously" about probability, only that the equality _suggests_ that it comes from a probability question (which indeed appears to be the case, looking at other question by OP). I am not going to continue arguing about what should be the solution set that we shall consider, because clarifying that should be OP's job.

Comment: Maybe the original question may help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649435/probability-of-an-event-based-on-percentage-in-fixed-lapse-of-time

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Substitute $x=1-p$, put the number $1$ on the other side of the equation, and multiply the equation by $-1$.